# is there a ubuntu22 package for python-omniorb

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-22.04, omniorb

I am upgrading to Ubuntu22 and need a package that I am using under ubuntu20 but cannot find it.  Is there a package for python-omniorb under ubuntu22?  I cannot find it in a ubuntu package search. Or is it replaced by something new? It contains python bindings for omniORB.